# Angular HTTP Patch only accept hard coded HTTP options as parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I struggled with the HTTP patch that Angular provides, noticed that the method `patch(url, body, options)` - which has a lot of overloaded functions - only accepts hard coded parameter for HTTP options.

Hard coded example which works:

```js
patchEntity(id: number): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    const url: string = `url-to-resource`;
    const body: string = `[{"op":"replace","path":"/id","value":345}]`;
    return this.httpClient.patch(url, body, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'}),
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'text'
    });
}
```

Outsourced HTTP options that is responding with the following error message:

`Type Observable<ArrayBuffer> is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpResponse<string>>`

`Type 'ArrayBuffer' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpResponse<string>': body, type, clone, headers, and 4 more.`

```js
patchEntity(id: number): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    const url: string = `url-to-resource`;
    const body: string = `[{"op":"replace","path":"/id","value":345}]`;
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'}),
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'text'
    }
    return this.httpClient.patch(url, body, httpOptions); // <--- errors occurs here
}
```

Seems, I'm missing some basic understanding of what's going on in Typescript or Angular.

Can somebody teach me why Angular do not let me outsourcing the HTTP options and the errors occur?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is clear. You are typing the return of this method as `Observable<HttpResponse<string>>`, however `this.httpClient.patch(url, body, httpOptions)` instead returns `Observable<ArrayBuffer>`. Either remove your type, update the type, or modify the the resulting value of `patch()` using something like `pipe` and `map` to transform into an Observable of a string. So the error is not related to options, it's related to the return type you specified for the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`observe` and `responseType` are *string unions*, so you need to mark them `as const` in your options object, otherwise Typescript will infer them as type `string`.

```
const httpOptions = {
  ...
  observe: 'response' as const,
  responseType: 'text' as const
}
```

You can read more about it in the official docs, at the end of [this section](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response)

Cheers

Comment: Yap, that's right. I only read the official docs [one section below](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) of your link :/ Totally missed the one you've linked. Thanks a lot for pointing that out. Cheers!